# Spring MVC POST not supportet

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc

i wan't to configure spring mvc via UrlBasedViewResolver in an existing webflow, JSF- Primefaces project cause i need clean URLs. Unfortunately my SearchForm get an

```
WARN PageNotFound:183 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

warn if it fires ajax or action.
In case of form action the associated method in my @ManagedBean dont get called.
Now, I ask you to help...

web.xml

```
<display-name>My Transport</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:res/conf/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFSULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>faceslets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOLVER_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>hot-sneaks</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoSessionIdFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>dev.le.tools.servlet.filter.SessionIdFromUrlRemoveFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- Spring security filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoSessionIdFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="de************" />
<context:component-scan base-package="de************" />

<import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
<import resource="webflow-config.xml" />
<import resource="security-config.xml" />


<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/views/" mapping="/WEB-INF/views/**"/> 


<bean id="defaultServletHttpRequestHandler"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter" />

<!-- JSF for representation layer. All JSF files under /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
</bean>

<bean id="userAuthenticationProvider" class="de.wiegand.mytransport.services.impl.UserAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

webflow-config.xml

```
<bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.HibernateFlowExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="facesContextListener"
    class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />


<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository
        max-executions="0" />
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices"
    development="true" />

<faces:resources />

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="flowUrlHandler">
        <bean class="de.wiegand.mytransport.ui.util.PrettyFlowUrlHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowUrlHandler">
        <bean class="de.wiegand.mytransport.ui.util.PrettyFlowUrlHandler" />
    </property>
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowUrlHandler">
        <bean class="de.wiegand.mytransport.ui.util.PrettyFlowUrlHandler" />
    </property>
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />
```

search.xhtml

```
<p:fieldset styleClass="fieldset_search" legend="Fahrt suchen">
        <h:form id="searchTripForm">
            <p:focus />
            <h:panelGrid id="searchPanelGrid"
                style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; text-align: right"
                cellspacing="8" columns="3">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="Von:" />
                    <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:autoComplete id="origin_autocomplete" minQueryLength="3"
                    rendered="#{empty searchBean.notUniqueOrigins}"
                    forceSelection="false" queryDelay="300" maxResults="5"
                    placeholder="PLZ, Stadt oder Statdtteil" charset="UTF-8"
                    value="#{searchBean.originDisplayNameAndClearGeoLocation}"
                    required="true" label="Von" title="Absendeadresse eingeben"
                    tabindex="false"
                    completeMethod="#{geoNamesService.getGeoNamesByInput}" />
                <h:panelGrid rendered="#{!empty searchBean.notUniqueOrigins}"
                    columns="1">
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{searchBean.selectedNotUniqueOriginId}"
                        style="width:200px;" onchange="submit()"
                        valueChangeListener="#{searchBean.changeSelectedOrigin}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.notUniqueOrigins}"
                            var="origin" itemLabel="#{origin.name}, #{origin.zipcode}"
                            itemValue="#{origin.id}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:commandLink id="resetOriginToInput" style="margin-right:20px;"
                        immediate="true" ajax="false" action="resetOriginToInput">
                        <h:outputText value="zurücksetzen" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:message id="originMsg" for="origin_autocomplete" />
                    <p:tooltip for="origin_autocomplete" styleClass="tooltip"
                        showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="Nach:" />
                    <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:autoComplete id="destination_autocomplete" minQueryLength="3"
                    queryDelay="300"
                    rendered="#{empty searchBean.notUniqueDestinations}"
                    forceSelection="false" charset="UTF-8" maxResults="5"
                    placeholder="PLZ, Stadt oder Statdtteil"
                    value="#{searchBean.destinationDisplayNameAndClearGeoLocation}"
                    effect="fade" required="true" label="Nach"
                    title="Empfängeradresse eingeben"
                    completeMethod="#{geoNamesService.getGeoNamesByInput}" />
                <h:panelGrid
                    rendered="#{!empty searchBean.notUniqueDestinations}"
                    columns="1">
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{searchBean.selectedNotUniqueDestinationId}"
                        style="width:200px;" onchange="submit()"
                        valueChangeListener="#{searchBean.changeSelectedDestination}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.notUniqueDestinations}"
                            var="destination"
                            itemLabel="#{destination.name}, #{destination.zipcode}"
                            itemValue="#{destination.id}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:commandLink id="resetDestinationToInput" ajax="false"
                        immediate="true" style="margin-right:20px;"
                        action="resetDestinationToInput">
                        <h:outputText value="zurücksetzen" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:message id="destinationMsg" for="destination_autocomplete" />
                    <p:tooltip for="destination_autocomplete" styleClass="tooltip"                      showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:panelGrid>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView init() {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("suche*");
    return mav; 
}   
@RequestMapping(value="/suche*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView search(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("views/suche");
    return mav; 
}
    @RequestMapping(value="/suche*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView _search(SearchRequestBean searchBean, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("views/suche");
    return mav; 
}
    @RequestMapping(value="/detail*", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView detail() {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("views/detail");
    return mav; 
}
```

T   hank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any methods in your controller that accept a POST request? So far you're only showing ones that accept GET requests.

Comment: sry... lost in try and error. Post method iss added in first post.

Comment: Tell us for which URL it is not supported.

Comment: Console: "WARN PageNotFound:183 - Request method 'POST' not supported" and BrowserResponse says: "HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /app/WEB-INF/views/suche.xhtml. Reason:
Request method 'POST' not supported"
THX